# How to watch typescript files in the background continuously without blocking the terminal?

Tags: node.js, typescript, bash

Is there a way to run `tsc -w` without blocking the terminal? In other words, is there a way to watch typescript files continuously, without blocking the terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Run it as a background process. For example, if you're using bash:

```sh
tsc -w &
```

If you want to suppress the output:

```sh
tsc -w &>/dev/null &
```

Though this means if there are any errors, you won't see them. You could pipe the output to a file instead of `/dev/null` so that you could always `less` or `tail` the file anytime you needed to check what's up.

Comment: I tried your first option and it worked. But then I tried putting it in an npm script, and then it didn't work.

Comment: Never mind, I had to put the '&' after the npm run command. Thanks!

Comment: I was just about to tell you that. It won't work within the script, because npm is not using bash internally, or is kicking off a shell process in its own way. But as you figured out, you simply have to do it to the outer bash command.